# Selenium: I couldn't make a bot that logs into a website with Cloudflare

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cloudflare, bypass

The first link was just a Selenium script for access to YouTube:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\prog\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://youtube.com")
```

This Python program works perfectly fine,
but when I try the same thing with a Cloudflare-protected website, it gets stuck in the wait page.
I did some research and found an undetected Chrome driver to use, but I keep getting errors like "RuntimeError".

The libraries are all perfectly installed. I
did more research and found a YouTube video that I could follow, but I’m still getting errors.
Here is the second code:

```
import selenium
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import time
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
py = "24.172.82.94:53281"
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % py)
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://ifconfig.me/")
time.sleep(4)
```

The error I get:

> AttributeError: 'ChromeOptions' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

For something related to processes, which I cannot fully understand, you have to the lines `driver = uc.Chrome()` and  `driver.get('https://namecheap.com')` in the `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Also the link has to have the `https://` or `http://` for it to work.

Here's my working code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc # The .v2 is not necessary in the last version of undetected_chromedriver
import time
def main():
    time.sleep(4)
    # Continue your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://namecheap.com')
    main()
```